# Adding R code to documentation about an R data set using roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am trying to document how the data in a built in data set was created using `roxygen2`. Here is my details section:

````
@details
#' This data set consists of 200 observations generated using the following code:
#' ```{r}
#' set.seed(123)
#' N = 200
#' bsort.df = data.frame(n = rep(0, N), time = rep(0, N))
#'
#' n = sample(100:1000, size = N, replace = TRUE)
#'
#' pb = txtProgressBar(0, N, style = 3)
#'
#' for(i in 1:N){
#'   x = rnorm(n[i])
#'   bsort.df$n[i] = n[i]
#'   bsort.df$time[i] = system.time(bubbleSort(x))[1]
#'   setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
#' }
#' close(pb)
#' ```
````

This gets rendered in R studio as:

[image]

which isn't what I expect or want. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I just copied your code (assuming it's missing a `#'` before `@details`), and it renders as expected (though including the `{r}` after your first set of backticks seems to execute it as well as rendering it).  Maybe it's a weird whitespace issue?

Comment: Thanks @Hobo - will look a little harder